# Declaring Python variables with a specific type

Tags: python, variables

Python allows me to make the following statement...

```
records = list()
```

ie declare a name/variable that is at present of type 'List'

The following syntax does not throw a syntax error but I'm not sure what it actually does...

```
records: list()
```

Any ideas when you might use the colon version? Why is it syntactically correct if when I query its type I get an error?

```
records = list()
print(type(records)

>> <class 'list'>

records: list()
print(type(records)

>> NameError: name 'records' is not defined
```

Comment: It's a type hint that says that when you assign to the variable you'll give it a value whose type is whatever `list()` returns.

Comment: Note that it should be `records: list` without the `()`.

Comment: Great thanks Barmar - fully understood - apart from a quick follow-up, why not the parentheses?

Comment: @templegate `list` is a type, `list()` is an expression that happens to evaluate to a list object. Type checkers won't understand the latter

Comment: `records = list()` doesn't declare the type of the variable. It calls the function `list()`, which returns a list, and assigns that value to the variable. Nothing stops you from doing `records = 3` after that.